# Is there a way to get the DateTimeZone from a Joda Time DateTime?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

This could be a case of me missing something, but this is weird. Looking at the JodaTime [DateTime API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?org/joda/time/DateTime.html), I'm clearly able to construct a `DateTime` with a [DateTimeZone](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?org/joda/time/DateTime.html). But I can't seem to find a way of asking a particular DateTime instance about which time zone it's in, which is leading to a case of programming mismatched expectations. Little help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the getZone() method to get the DateTimeZone instance used

Comment: Ah, comes from the `AbstractInstant`. Didn't see that, thanks.